# How to Roll back newly applied LTS Maintenance Upgrade to the Previous Version

Tags: 10.04, server, upgrade, lts

Is there a way to roll back a LTS Maintenance Upgrade to the previous version, say from 10.04.02 LTS from 10.04.03 LTS ?

I am not facing a problem now, but need to figure out means to back out the packages before I rollover to 10.04.03 LTS on my server, in case of any need.

Comment: The only way I'd do that is with a full backup of the hdd.
Trying to downgrade in apt is too risky/painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one step process to roll-back all the updates done in a point release to the previous one. We will need to track and revert each of the updates.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the point releases of 10.04 are just roll-ups of the packages from the `security` and `updates` archives.  If you have been regularly applying the updates to your server (which is the recommended behaviour), you are probably already at the new point release.

If you have upgraded to a package that is causing you problems, you can downgrade a package.  You can discover what versions of a package are available with the following command:

```
apt-cache policy PACKAGE_NAME
```

Note the version numbers it lists for each archive.  You can install a specific version of a package with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install PACKAGE_NAME=VERSION_NUMBER
```

You will be warned that you are downgrading the package.

Comment: As per my understanding point releases are for updating patches in more systematic fashion on production like servers. So I do point release upgrades on my servers so that I can evaluate any impact. Now if I am facing a problem when I do an update, I would need to roll back. Since I am upgrading multiple packages in a point release upgrade, I do not know how I can identify a specific package easily. So I was looking for an option to roll back all 'recently' upgraded packages to previous version. (Compare with IBM AIX Apply and revert of an SP, if you are aware).