# apt get rollback in time?

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, restore

I installed packages in the last days and I decided.
I try to removed them, and chrome was suddenly stop working.
I assume that some of the packages were already installed, so chrome couldn't start anymore.
so I installed them again.
is there a way to restore to the package state insatlled in the system, 3 days ago for instance?

Comment: How did you remove the packages? Chrome is a snap package, so it essentially only depends on a good install of the snap framework, not on your system packages. You must have broken snap then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default Ubuntu, there is no way to restore your package state to a previous state. You can however downgrade individual packages using the procedure indicated in another [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54167/how-to-roll-back-newly-applied-lts-maintenance-upgrade-to-the-previous-version).

The software **Timeshift** allows to take "snapshots" of the system, so you can roll back to a previous state. It is installed by default in Linux Mint, but you can also install and use it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Would Timeshift roll back just the installed packages or all changes made across the system, and if yes, don't you think it is an overkill?

Comment: All changes. OP does not indicate resetting specific packages (which?). The question was " is there a way to restore to the package state insatlled in the system, 3 days ago for instance?", so I interpreted this as setting the system back to the state it was three days ago. That is what Timeshift is designed for.

Comment: Indeed, the question was about the "package state" only, not changes to /etc/fstab, bookmarks or anything else. Also, how is Timeshift supposed to help if it wasn't installed, and there aren't any snapshots?

Comment: It can help in the future if the user wants a facility to roll back the system. I started my answer stating that, by default, it is not possible in Ubuntu and linked to an answer where one can learn to downgrade individual packages. By the way, Timeshift will not revert your bookmarks, only system wide configuration.